# Javascript stop TR click event on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I want to capture what option has been selected from dropdown. Here the problem is when option is being clicked TR click event is called because `select` doesn't have click event. 
How can I stop TR click event when drop down is clicked?

```
<html>
<script>
    function check1() {
        alert("TR clicked");
    }

    function check2() {
        alert("drop_down clicked");
    }
</script>
<table border=1>
    <tr onclick="check1();">
        <td>My Options</td>
        <td>        
            <select name="" id="drop_down" onchange="check2();">
              <option value="A">A</option>
              <option value="B">B</option>  
            </select>           
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you want `<tr>` to fire if  `<select>` wasn't clicked? Check my answer if so.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture `click` event on `<select>` and prevent its propagation:

```
function onSelectClick(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
}
<select onclick="onSelectClick">
```

or you can try to simply return `false` for `click` event for `<select>`:

```
<select onclick="return false;">
```

Comment: It seems not working as on dropdown click TR click event is being called.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check what element triggered the click, and if it was the drop down, ignore the event:

```
function check1(e) {
    if (typeof e == "undefined")
        e = window.event;
    if (e.srcElement.id != "drop_down") {
        alert("TR clicked");
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/oqgdh59o/)

---

If you want the JS to be more generic and not check for specific ID of elements, you can also change its logic to look for elements having a custom attribute defined:

```
function check1(e) {
    if (typeof e == "undefined")
        e = window.event;
    if (e) {
        var sourceElement = e.srcElement || e.target;
        if (sourceElement) {
            if (sourceElement.getAttribute("data-stop-propagation")) {
                //element being clicked asked to ignore the event, abort
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    alert("TR clicked");
}
```

To make it work with your code, change the HTML to this: (the value of the attribute doesn't matter)

```
<select name="" id="drop_down" onchange="check2();" data-stop-propagation="1">
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqgdh59o/1/)

Comment: `window.event` is specific to [MSIE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event)

Comment: Actually I don't want to change `check1()` which is generic for many pages.

Comment: @Flying no, I tested this with Chrome.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, take a look at compatibility table by the link, i've provided

Comment: @Flying only Firefox doesn't support this. Anyway, made my code better and linked to the fiddle.

Comment: @amicngh I'm afraid that won't be possible. But if you can change the HTML itself and add custom attributes then see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

one more thing you can do is get event target,

```
  function check1() {
   if(this.event.target.nodeName!=='SELECT'){
    alert("TR clicked");
   }
}
```

to support in all browsers just capture event and pass it as param

```
<tr onclick=check1(event)>....</tr>
//in js
function check1(event) {
   if(event.target.nodeName!=='SELECT'){
    alert("TR clicked");
   }
}
```

Comment: i think you have to pass event for IE . i.e in tr onclick=check1(event)

Answer (score 1):

Use `addEventListener()` instead of inline attribute eventHandlers. At the end of the `eventListener()`, or at the end of callback, add `e.stopPropagation()` so the event never bubbles thereby never reaching `<tr>`.

`<tr>` will need to be referenced as it is relative to another table component such as `<table>` or `<td>`. Although inline attribute events stick to anything (including a `<tr>` tag), it will become detrimental to maintaining such a layout (as I suspect it is already occurring). This is why it has been strongly suggested that `addEventListener()` be used instead of inline events.

In the following demo:

- If `<select>` is clicked the console logs its value.
- If a `<td>` is clicked then it logs a generic 'click'
- It will not log both at click event

All modern browsers are supported

**Details commented in demo**

### Demo

```js
var table = document.querySelector('table');

function chk() {
  var drop = document.getElementById('drop');
  var val = drop.value
  console.log(val);
}

function rowLog() {
  console.log('Clicked');
}

table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  /* if the clicked element (e.target) is NOT
  || the element registered to listen for
  || click event (table) then...
  */
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {

    /* if clicked element's #id is drop
    || call function chk()
    */
    if (e.target.id === 'drop') {
      chk();
      
      /* Stop the event from bubbling (thereby 
      || event never reaches TR if #drop is clicked)
      */
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
    /* TR is tightly integrated with TD so
    || target TD or spicify TBODY or TABLE
    || to reference TR.
    || Note e.stopPropagation() is not invoked
    || in this function so click event will
    || bubble to <tr>
    */
    else if(e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
      rowLog();
    }
  }
  
}, false);
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>My Options</td>
    <td>
      <select name="" id="drop">
              <option></option>
              <option value="A">A</option>
              <option value="B">B</option>  
            </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to work best for me:

```
<html>
<script>
    function check1(event) {
        // check if the event path contains the select element
        // Not checking null values for simplicity
        var preventFlag = event.path.filter(obj => 
                            obj.id.include('select')).length > 0
        if(!preventFlag) {
          // triggered only when preventFlag is false
          alert("TR clicked");
        }
    }

    function check2() {
        alert("drop_down clicked");
    }
</script>
<table border=1>
    <tr onclick="check1(event);">
        <td>My Options</td>
        <td>        
            <select name="" id="drop_down" onchange="check2();">
              <option value="A">A</option>
              <option value="B">B</option>  
            </select>           
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The good thing about this solution is that it works for all child elements inside the desired target element. For e.g, this logic works when a select element is clicked and it also works when any of the options inside the select element are clicked.

Downside: the path array needs to be looped through.