# Javascript stop TR click event on dropdown selection| Not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling

I want to capture what option has been selected from dropdown.
Here the problem is when `option` is being clicked `TR` click event is called because select doesn't have click event.

How can I stop `TR` click event when `dropdown` is clicked?

```js
function check1(e) {
  if (typeof e == "undefined")
    e = window.event;
  if (e) {
    var sourceElement = e.srcElement || e.target;
    if (sourceElement) {
      if (sourceElement.getAttribute("data-stop-propagation")) {
        //element being clicked asked to ignore the event, abort
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  alert("TR clicked");
}

function check2() {
  alert("drop_down clicked");
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr onclick="check1();">
    <td>My Options</td>
    <td>
      <select name="" id="drop_down" onchange="check2();" data-stop-propagation="1">
              <option value="A">A</option>
              <option value="B">B</option>  
            </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/oqgdh59o/3/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908957/javascript-stop-tr-click-event-on-dropdown-selection)

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need the TR to have a click event at all. Why can't you do what's needed with the select changed handler?

Comment: I have been working on an existing project where clicking on TR opening some different page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking it back a bit, `select.click` executes before `tr.click` which executes before `select.change` event. Why not just stop propagation when the select is clicked?

```js
function check1() {
  alert("TR clicked");
}

function check2() {
  alert("drop_down clicked");
}

function stopPropagation() {
  event.stopPropagation();
};
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr onclick="check1();">
    <td>My Options</td>
    <td>
      <select name="" id="drop_down" onclick="stopPropagation();" onchange="check2();" data-stop-propagation="1">
              <option value="A">A</option>
              <option value="B">B</option>  
            </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```